# Google analytics stopped working for some pages on 25 of April

Tags: google-analytics

I have the google analytics tracking code setup on a couple of our websites (We are using the analytics.js version of it).

This all worked fine until April 25th after which we stopped seeing any data shown in google analytics for one of our tracking codes. No active users, no events, just as if the pages stopped sending anything.

I checked our pages with the Google Tag Assistant and all seems to be working fine there. The events and pageviews are sent correctly and receive a 200 OK response.

Could this be something related to GDPR? We have accepted the Data Processing Amendment and have added a contact person for GDPR.

** EDIT **

Ok I figured it out. Someone added a filter in the Admin dashboard to the "All Website Data" view.

If someone comes across a similar issue, check Admin -> Change history to see if any changes where done in your admin panel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is a good point @DaImTo, is it good behaviour to ask the question there already or should I wait until this question is closed here?